# Top level of JSON files, object? array?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using flutter/dart to fetch JSON files from Google Sheet. I use 2 different methods to get the same Google sheet, one is by scripting and the other is from 'sheetlabs' service. However, sheetlabs works and scripting fails. The top level from sheetlabs is an array while the top level from scripting is an object.

I just copy the scripting file from YouTube and I have no idea of google scripting. How can I modify the scripting code to make the top level being and array just like sheetlabs' file?

The structure of google sheet is relatively simple-- 10 columns with 'stockcode','stockname' ,etc as header which are freezed. Six stocks' data in rows.

Below is the scripting code.

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY ORIGINAL GOOGLE SHEET'S URL ADDRESS");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  
  return getUsers(sheet);
  
}

function getUsers(sheet){
  var jo = {};
  var dataArray = [];
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){
    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['stockname'] = dataRow[0];
    record['stockcode'] = dataRow[1];
    record['marketvalue'] = dataRow[2];
    record['amount'] = dataRow[3];
    record['currentprice'] = dataRow[4];
    record['averagecost'] = dataRow[5];
    record['profit'] = dataRow[6];
    record['profitpercent'] = dataRow[7];
    record['previousclosingprice'] = dataRow[8];
    record['todaysprofit'] = dataRow[9];
   
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
  
  jo.user = dataArray;
  
  var result = JSON.stringify(jo);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);

}
```

[image: JSON structure from scripting]

[image: JSON structure from sheetlabs]

Comment: Can you try this: `jo.user = dataArray.flat([1]);` instead ?

Comment: unfortunately, the same...

Comment: If you don't want json why do you use json object in the for loop ?

Comment: Fantastic ! I comment out var jo={}; and replace' jo.user....' with 'var result = JSON.stringify(dataArray);

It works !
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create json objects in the for loop.

You need to comment out `var jo = {};`

The following should work:

```
function doGet(e){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("MY ORIGINAL GOOGLE SHEET'S URL ADDRESS");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheet1");
  
  return getUsers(sheet);
  
}

function getUsers(sheet){
  var dataArray = [];
  var rows = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  for(var i = 0, l= rows.length; i<l ; i++){

    var dataRow = rows[i];
    var record = {};
    record['stockname'] = dataRow[0];
    record['stockcode'] = dataRow[1];
    record['marketvalue'] = dataRow[2];
    record['amount'] = dataRow[3];
    record['currentprice'] = dataRow[4];
    record['averagecost'] = dataRow[5];
    record['profit'] = dataRow[6];
    record['profitpercent'] = dataRow[7];
    record['previousclosingprice'] = dataRow[8];
    record['todaysprofit'] = dataRow[9];
   
    dataArray.push(record);
  }
    
  var result = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(result).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```